# Cannot pass variables to a partial in handlebars 3

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Tried to pass variable to a partial without success.

---

**Try 1**: passing template context

"product" template:

```
From template: {{product.name}} 
<br>
{{> product_buttons}}
```

"product_buttons" partial:

```
From partial: {{product.name}}
```

Output:

```
From template: Awesome Steel Shoes
<br>
[object Object]
From partial:
```

We can see 2 problems:

- the partial does not render the expected value. I also tried to render the template with `{{> product_buttons this}` and `{{> product_buttons product=product}` for the exact same result
- `[object Object]`is inserted in the output

---

**Try 2**: passing hash variable

"product" template:

```
From template: {{product.name}} 
<br>
{{> product_buttons thename=product.name}}
```

"product_buttons" partial:

```
From partial: {{thename}}
```

This raises the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'thename' of undefined` at the following line from the compiled partial:

```
return "From partial: "
+ this.escapeExpression(((helper = (helper = helpers.thename || (depth0 != null ? depth0.thename : depth0)) != null ? helper : helpers.helperMissing),(typeof helper === "function" ? helper.call(depth0,{"name":"thename","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
                                                     ^--- Error is from here
+ "";
```

---

**Additional notes**

I pre-compile the templates with command line handlebars utility. I use handlebars 3.0.3 installed from npm, but the output of `handlebars -v`is "3.0.1" strangely. I checked paths and installations and cannot fix that either

Compilation command:

```
handlebars directory/*.handlebars -f file_name.tmpl.js
```

Template usage example:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('product_buttons', Handlebars.templates.product_buttons);
product = {name: 'test'};
html = Handlebars.templates.product({product: product});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please show how you compile and run your templates as your example is working as shown here: http://plnkr.co/edit/JrKBNnKOxDhqMUCw6Spp?p=preview

Comment: Added in the last section of my question, let me know if you need more infor. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info. I created an answer with the steps to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following steps to verify your example. First I created the two templates:

```
$ cat directory/product.handlebars 
From template: {{product.name}} 
<br>
{{> product_buttons}}

$ cat directory/product_buttons.handlebars
From partial: {{product.name}}
```

Then I compiled them

```
$ handlebars directory/*.handlebars -f file_name.tmpl.js
```

and got `file_name.tmpl.js`:

```
(function() {
  var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
templates['product_buttons'] = template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var stack1;

  return "From partial: "
    + this.escapeExpression(this.lambda(((stack1 = (depth0 != null ? depth0.product : depth0)) != null ? stack1.name : stack1), depth0));
},"useData":true});
templates['product'] = template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var stack1;

  return "From template: "
    + this.escapeExpression(this.lambda(((stack1 = (depth0 != null ? depth0.product : depth0)) != null ? stack1.name : stack1), depth0))
    + " \n<br>\n"
    + ((stack1 = this.invokePartial(partials.product_buttons,depth0,{"name":"product_buttons","data":data,"helpers":helpers,"partials":partials})) != null ? stack1 : "");
},"usePartial":true,"useData":true});
})();
```

I then included `file_name.tmpl.js` in my `index.html` and rendered the template like this

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('product_buttons', Handlebars.templates.product_buttons);
var context = {product: {name: 'My product'}};
html = Handlebars.templates.product(context);
console.log(html);
```

giving me this console output:

```
From template: My product 
<br>
From partial: My product
```

I saw that you did not set a context to your product template. But I guess this is just missing in your example, right?

Can you please verify (and post if different) the content of your `file_name.tmpl.js`?

Btw: My version of handlebars is 3.0.1 as well:

```
$ handlebars -v
3.0.1
```

I created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LVNqaS39MUPWJ4jBkQRc?p=preview) using the `file_name.tmpl.js`.

Comment: Yes there is a context in my source file, I just forgot it during the copy-paste. Context content comes from a data source, and was verified and is correct. I also set the context content manually to verify, same result

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr? You can fork mine if you like and add your `file_name.tmpl.js` and `handlebar.js`

Comment: I updated my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LVNqaS39MUPWJ4jBkQRc?p=preview) with your compiled template and this is working. Check the comment count of 12 for example. What version  of handlebars do you include in your website?

Comment: Ok solution found (not tested yet, but seems to be it) my handlebars runtime was v2.0.0. Will update to 3.0.3 and test again. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm glad I could help & I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I confirm, my mistake was to include an old version. It's working now.